# Entity Framework: Custom proxies for POCO

Tags: proxy, lazy-loading, entity-framework-6

I am working with the EF6 and I am a big fan of the dynamic proxies, which enables lazy loading and change tracking. Anyway I am not happy, that the lazy loading is triggered once the property is accessed instead of loading the data, when the enumerator or the count property is called first. Therefore I tried to diesable the proxys and replace them by custom proxies. It was an easy thing to use a custom object context and overload the CreateObject method. Unfortantly the ObjectMaterialized event cannot replace the entity and I am not able to replace an entity from a query. The creation of the object lies deep in internal classes of the framework.

Has anybody an idea how to use custom proxies? Or how I am able to replace the entities materialized in an object query?

Answer (score 1):

You should `.Include` the properties you want to fetch so that you avoid an [N+1 query problem](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/02/09/writing-efficient-queries-with-entity-framework-code-first-part-2.aspx).

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set ;}

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set ; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set ;}

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }
}

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Then this is **BAD** in that it'll do tons of queries:

```
using (var db = new BlogContext())
{
    var user = db.Users.Single(u => u.Id=5));  // +1 query
    foreach (var post in user.Posts) // N queries
    {
       var message = String.Format("{0} wrote {1}", user.Name, post.Title);
       Console.WriteLine(message);

       foreach (var comment in post.Comments) // N * M queries!
       {
           // and that .Author make N * M MORE!
           var message = String.Format("\t{0} commented {1}", comment.Author.Name, comment.Note);
           Console.WriteLine(message);
       }
    }
}
```

And this is **GOOD** in that it'll do *one* query:

```
using (var db = new BlogContext())
{
    var user = db.Users
                 .Single(u => u.Id=5))
                 .Include(u => u.Posts) // eliminates the N post queries
                 .Include(u => u.Posts.Comments) // eliminates the M comment queries
                 .Include(u => u.Posts.Comments.Author); // eliminates the M comment author queries

    foreach (var post in user.Posts) // N queries
    {
       var message = String.Format("{0} wrote {1}", user.Name, post.Title);
       Console.WriteLine(message);

       foreach (var comment in post.Comments) // N * M queries!
       {
           // and that .Author make N * M MORE!
           var message = String.Format("\t{0} commented {1}", comment.Author.Name, comment.Note);
           Console.WriteLine(message);
       }
    }
}
```